# Cost Function vs Precision/Recall

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

This question was also asked on [Andrew's Ng Coursera class forum](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/discussions/IkPi1ysVEeWw8CIACnuItg/replies/06NiPjBdEeWz1CIAC7fEHA).

I just finished watching [this video on skewed classes](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/68).

Andrew talks about an error function, which is not the same as the cost function, called the F Score. He suggests that perhaps it is better to compare different models based on the F Score rather than the cost function.

The question is why not just change the cost function? Or perhaps modify the cost function by adding a F Score term (similar to a regularization term).

It seems like one's objectives should be expressed in the cost function and only the cost function. Using another metric for evaluation or comparison seems indirect.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the cost function of some training problem. Typically we want to ensure that training problems are fairly efficiently solvable, e.g. through convex optimization. This places certain restrictions on the cost function.

Not all score functions we care about (e.g. F-score, area under the ROC curve, ...) lead to convex optimization problems. Hence, they are not used in the optimization problem directly.